# How I use async dispatch request. Getting ERROR: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have created a simple function in action.tsx file and calling dispatch function which results me error. Below is the code

index.txs file

```
const store: any =  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))(createStore)(rootReducer);

// store.subscribe(() => console.log("store", store.getState()));
// store.dispatch(miniFaq(store.getState()));
// store.dispatch(getCategoryQuestions(store.getState()));
const start: (Component: any) => void = (Component: any) => {
    render(
        (
            <AppContainer>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Component page={page}/>
                </Provider>
            </AppContainer>
        ),
        document.getElementById(mount),
    );
};

start(Main);
```

Comment: chnage type value to be a string `type: "SUBMIT_ANSWERS"`

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you are trying to dispatch your action like this:

```
store.dispatch(miniFaq(store.getState()))
```

...then it won’t work as **miniFaq** returns a function. As the error says, actions must be plain objects.

If you want to dispatch asynchronous actions then you can try some Redux middleware such as **redux-thunk**. The npm page is here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

So you would install **redux-thunk** as a dependency and apply it as middleware when you create your store (instructions on npm page).

Then you can write **miniFaq** to return a function that takes **dispatch** as an argument. The middleware will take care of calling this function with the store’s **dispatch** method.

Therefore, in the returned function, you can then use **dispatch** to dispatch your **submit** action asynchronously. Something like this:

```
const SUBMIT_ANSWERS = 'SUBMIT_ANSWERS'

function submit() {
  return {
    type: SUBMIT_ANSWERS,
    data: 'Test'
  }
}

function miniFaq() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(submit())
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

Now you can dispatch **miniFaq**:

```
store.dispatch(miniFaq(store.getState()))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: When I calling this action on page load then it is working fine but When I call the action on button click then I am facing the issue.

Comment: How are you calling it on button click?

Comment: I have a button on UI which is created in CategoryQuestionBox.tsx. On click of that I am calling the action. Below are the code of action, componenet and reducer.

I have updated the description above.

Comment: Are you using **mapDispatchToProps** and **connect** from **react-redux**? Where can I see your component code where your button is?